# Javascript alert for deleting mysql data opens in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, alert

I need to add JS alert for deleting certain records from mysql. Simple on... Sure you want to delete? Yes - leads to page to delete, No - does nothing. Problem is whenever i click on Yes it opens a new tab which i don't need (want all in current tab). Any solutions?

JS:

```
function confirmDelete(url) {
var aa = event.srcElement.id;
if (confirm("Sure to delete: "+ aa +"?")) {
    window.open('/www/site/m_delete.php?id=' + aa +'');
} else {
    return false;
}
```

}

HTML:

```
<a class="box_setting fa fa-ban" style="cursor:pointer;" id="'.$id.'" onClick="confirmDelete(\'/www/site/m_delete.php?id='.$id.'\')"></a>
```

Comment: try window.location.pathname('/m_delete.php?id=' + aa +'');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For opening the page in same tab use this code:-

```
 window.open('/www/site/m_delete.php?id=' + aa +'', '_self'); // _self refers to window/tab that the code is currently running
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple XMLHttpRequest to your delete page - this will be open this link in the background

```
function confirmDelete(url) {
    var aa = event.srcElement.id;
    if (confirm("Sure to delete: "+ aa +"?")) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", '/www/site/m_delete.php?id='+aa, true);
        xhttp.send();
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Docs: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
window.location('/www/site/m_delete.php?id=' + aa +'');
```

replace your code with this line only

Answer (score 0):

if **m_delete.php** just have php & mysql codes u can easily include this file in the beginning and put $_GET check in condition with it .

like in the beggining of the current page :

```
<?php 
     if(isset($_GET['id']))
     {
          include '/www/site/m_delete.php';
     }
?>
<!-- page content -->

function confirmDelete(url) {
var aa = event.srcElement.id;
if (confirm("Sure to delete: "+ aa +"?")) {
    window.location.href = '?id=' + aa;
} else {
    return false;
}
```